# django haystack in production, how do to python manage.py update_index automatically?

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When a user uploads a post, I use haystack search engine to allow users to search for that post. Every thing has worked in development, my worries is when in development I had to python manage.py rebuild_index to get started, and python manage.py update_index to update any added posts to be in search engine. how do I achieve this job automatically in production?

I'm using amazon elastic beanstalk, so I thought I would do this

```
 01_forhaystack:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python project/manage.py rebuild_index --noinput"

  02_forhaystack2:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python project/manage.py update_index --noinput"
```

will it work..?is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can update_index daily/hourly. Or even after each model insert/update. But better way would be to use signal and [Real Time Search](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/best_practices.html#real-time-search).

Answer (score 0):

just add the next line in *settings.py*.

```
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

if you need more information you can read the documentation [RealtimeSignalProcessor](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signal_processors.html#realtime-realtimesignalprocessor).